# Python-Turn turtle to the right

Tags: python

Is there any way to turn `turtle` to the right (to the East) in Python regardless of which direction the `turtle` is facing?

Really appreciate any help

Comment: Get the current [`heading`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.heading) and calculate the rotation needed.

Answer (score 1):

From the help page `help(turtle)`

```
 |  setheading(self, to_angle)
 |      Set the orientation of the turtle to to_angle.
 |      
 |      Aliases:  setheading | seth
 |      
 |      Argument:
 |      to_angle -- a number (integer or float)
 |      
 |      Set the orientation of the turtle to to_angle.
 |      Here are some common directions in degrees:
 |      
 |       standard - mode:          logo-mode:
 |      -------------------|--------------------
 |         0 - east                0 - north
 |        90 - north              90 - east
 |       180 - west              180 - south
 |       270 - south             270 - west
 |      
 |      Example (for a Turtle instance named turtle):
 |      >>> turtle.setheading(90)
 |      >>> turtle.heading()
 |      90
```